# Can not input password correctly under PuTTY to pg_dump a table

Tags: linux, postgresql

I use PuTTy to connect a remote Ubuntu. I want to transfer a table from another windows computer into a database in the Ubuntu.
I searched in the Internet and the code is

```
pg_dump -C -t table_name -h 192.168.1.106 -p 5432 database_name1| psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres database_name2
```

But the PuTTy shows:

```
Password for user postgres: Password:
```

I need to input two password: one is the Ubuntu user postgres pw, and the other is windows computer user postgres pw.

I guess the right way is to input Ubuntu user pw first, and then the computer pw. But it shows:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "database_name1" failed
```

Is this error caused by PuTTY? What would it be like if I use the Ubuntu computer directly?
I also used the separated way: first pg_dump, then psql. It worked.
Can anyone tell me why I can not transfer a table using pg_dump | psql directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work well because both programs are trying to read from the same terminal input stream at the same time. Some of them get some parts of each of what you type, so passwords are mangled.

Use [a `~/.pgpass` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) to supply the passwords, or use the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable:

```
PGPASSWORD='pw_for_dump' pg_dump .... | PGPASSWORD='pw_for_restore' pg_restore ...
```

The `.pgpass` file is preferable.

Comment: Thanks! @Ringer. Now I know the reason of this error.